# Pandas: Trouble Stripping HTML Tags From DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a `text` column containing HTML.  I want to get just the text, aka strip the tags.  I try to do this below as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result_df['text'] = BeautifulSoup(result_df['text']).get_text()
```

However, I end up getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result_df['text'] = [BeautifulSoup(text).get_text() for text in result_df['text'] ]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could alternatively use an approach that uses `apply`, although I doubt it makes much difference.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'a': ['<div><span>something</span></div>', '<a href="nowhere.org">erowhon</a>']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
                                   a
0  <div><span>something</span></div>
1  <a href="nowhere.org">erowhon</a>
>>> import bs4
>>> df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: bs4.BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml').get_text())
>>> df
           a
0  something
1    erowhon
```

Comment: Make sure to remove all missing data using 'df.dropna()' before applying the lambda function, otherwise you will get 'TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()' error if your data frame has missing data.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv("./testlog.tsv", index_col=0,delimiter='\t')
X = df.review
df['review'] = [BeautifulSoup(X).getText() for X in df['review']]
```

This will remove any HTML tags from the column review in the file testlog.

Comment: How is this approach different from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704135/8881141)? Please do not post duplicates of already existing answers.